# Syntax for Alter Column and Add Column in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table

Is it possible to both alter a column and add a new column in the same alter table query for MSQL? I've tried looking at the below MSDN article, but it was a bit confusing to understand. I could easily do it with multiple queries, but would rather do it with one query if possible.  Thanks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no you need to do it in separate batches

```
create table test(id int)
go

alter table Test add id2 int
go
alter table Test ALTER COLUMN id DECIMAL (5, 2)
```

you can however add more than 1 column at a time

```
alter table Test add id3 int, id4 int
go
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was kinda what I was finding in my searching.